# Getting confused with Bootstrap col-xs-8

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want my sign in box to only fill 8 of the columns that bootstrap provides. Currecntly this is what I have written for the div:

```
<div class="shadow bg-white rounded col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 tile">
```

However this is the current result I'm getting...

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: What result did you expect? maybe show it and share more of your code.

Comment: Add more of your code or create fiddle for the same.

Comment: Read [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com). There is no -xs in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `col-xs-8` class in `bootstrap 4.1`. this is new class in bootstrap 4.1 for small devices `col-8`. Try This

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="shadow bg-white rounded col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-8 tile">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put inside the `container` and then make the `offset`

```
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
```

Note: I'm not sure whether this will answer your question or not 'cause you didn't provide the question clearly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <label>Email</label><br>
      <input type="email" class="form-control">
      <label>Password</label><br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control">
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Login</button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put inside the `container` and then make the `offset` of xs class like this

```
<div class="shadow bg-white rounded col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 tile">
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to Wrap it into a Row.

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="shadow bg-white rounded col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 tile">
       ....Your Input stuff etc...
       </div>
    </div>
```

You probably also want `justify-content-center` so your content (input) is in the center of 
the page.

[More Infos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)